# I am not able to access variable a of class

Tags: java, arraylist

How to typecast the objects obtained from `ArrayList` generically?

`get(index)` returns the elements based on the type we pass. But here in generic I am passing `T` as a parameter of `ArrayList`. That's when I am trying to access element in list I have to typecast it explicitly. But I can't hard-code.

Kindly provide me solution how can I do typecasting without hard-code.

```
// obj.get(0).a is throwing error : Variable a is not found in Object class.

import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    int a;

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        ArrayList<Test> t = new ArrayList<Test>();
        Test t1 = new Test();
        t1.a=9;
        Test t2 = new Test();
        t1.a=9;
        t.add(t1);
        t.add(t2);
        new B().finf(t);
    }

}

class B {
    public <T> void finf(ArrayList<T> obj) {
        try {
            System.out.println((obj.get(0)).a); 
        } catch(Exception e) { } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you declare obj as an ArrayList<T> if it actually only can be an ArrayList (or List) of Test? This method should not be generic, and should take a List<Test> (or a List<? extends Test>) as argument.

Comment: `public <T extends Test> void finf(List<T> obj)`

Comment: I think you have a small typo also. You didn't set `t2.a`.

Comment: I have considered it for one class but what if i have to use more than one class.

Comment: If you want a generic "finf" method (whatever that could mean) that needs to be able to handle lists of several types, then all these types need to have something in common: a common superclass, or a common interface. For example, The method [sort() in ava.util.Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) accepts any type T, provided T implements Comparable, because it makes no sense to sort things that are not comparable. If finf() needs to access a property a of type int, then you should define an interface containing `int getA()`.